# Display 2nd field based on the selection in the dropdownlist

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I am having short names displayed in the dropdownlist, I want, on the selection of any value in the dropdownlist a text-box should display the corresponding FULL-NAME from another table.

The short name is displayed from the selection of the record in the first grid-screen, hence coming from another table and the full name along with the short name (also) reside on the other table.

Comment: What method are you using to render out the dropdownlist? Have you considered using data elements on each option to append the full name so you can bind a change event listener?

Answer (score 0):

Can use `DataTextField` and `DataValueField`.  When you create the collection you join the other table so the collection has both values.   I assume you mean a `ComboBox`.  `DropDownList` is not a UI control.

[DropDownList Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx)

Comment: From the tags, this is an MVC app not a Windows Form app.

Comment: @NickBork Correct I put in another link

Comment: Thats still a Windows form control. Either way, in a Web app you can already specify the Text and Value of a dropdown. What often happens is you want an ID to be the value and some string to be the text. In this case, it sounds like Rajat wants to also pull in a third value for display purposes when something is selected. There are several ways to store that information and read it out. All of those methods will be different than any Windows form controls.

Comment: @NickBork I may get this right on the the third try.  Thanks!  If I am wrong again then I will just delete it.

Comment: Friends, thanks for the reply, actually I am working on ASP.NET-MVC3 technology where I don't get the asp controls but only the HTML controls. I even dont get the server side events like Page_load etc.